# how to find logged-in users using sorcery?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sorcery

Is there any way to find the currently logged-in users and delete the sessions of particular users using sorcery?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery#api-summary):

```
Below is a summary of the library methods. Most method names are self explaining and the rest are commented:

# activity logging
current_users
```

You can use `current_users` to iterate through all your users. To log them out have a look at [reset_session](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html).

Comment: Can you explain a bit more the issue you have with these columns? They should be filled automatically by **sorcery** I think